# How to fix Non-Google cost campaign misclassification in GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

GA4 Non-Google Cost view shows Google Display campaigns. This a misclassification. Any idea how to solve it?

There is a new UTM called "**source_platform**" that differentiates what comes from **Google **and **Manual **(any other provider | there are other categories but not relevant for this topic).

I have checked the number of sessions that comes as Google from Display campaigns and it is higher than the numbers in Manual. However, having a rounded 20% of traffic assigned as Manual is relevant and affects the overall distinction between Google/Non Google reports.

Do you have any idea how could I fix this misattribution? Thank you in advance.